# How do I constantly read lines appended to a file, in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

The pythonic equivalent of what I'm looking for (in NodeJS) is:

```py
handle = open("file_appended_to_every_second.txt", "w+")
def get_new_entries() -> str:
    handle.read()
```

Comment: maybe https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#event-line ?

Comment: or better, this https://github.com/logdna/tail-file-node#example-using-readline